# Question related to analytical geometry.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

For a positive real number a, let S(a) denote the set of points (x, y) satistying
|x|^a + |y|^a  = 1
A positive number a is said to be good if the points in S(a) that are closest to the origin lie only on the coordinate axes. Then

(A) all $a$ in $(0, 1)$ are good and others are not good.

(B) all $a$ in $(1,2)$ are good and others are not good.

(C) all $a> 2$ are good and others are not good.

(D) all $a >1$ are good and others are not good.

Is there anyway to determine the nature of the curve for values like a=1/2 or 1/3 or for a>2 and specifically to determine whether a wud be good or bad?
I can't see anyway to determine so even for only the 1st quadrant

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to put values like a = 2 but for fraction values like a=1/2,1/3, plotting the graph becomes very difficult without calculater

Comment: We are not here to blindly answer your homework questions. Please show us what work you have done towards answering this question so far and we will be able to help get you unstuck. If you truly cannot get started, then write down all the techniques that you have learnt about to solve similar questions so we can write an answer at the right level of knowledge for you

Comment: These are not homework questions, these are questions from a reputed entrance examination like the IMO

Comment: I don't know how to plot the graph for values like a = 1/2, 1/3, 3, 4 etc.

Comment: What lioness99a was trying to say is, you should always include your own thoughts in the body of the question. Please click on the tiny `edit` button and improve the post.

Comment: First of all, you have to realize that it is enough to work in the first quadrant ($x \geq 0, y \geq 0)$, Do you see why ?

Comment: Besides, your title mentions "volumes". I don't see why...

Comment: The points of the curve on the axes are $(\pm 1, 0), (0, \pm 1)$ at a distance of $1$. so the question is whether points off the axis are closer or farther away than $1$. As Jean Marie has said, you only need to look at the case where $x, y \ge 0$, which helpfully gets rid of the absolute values. I also suggest rewriting it in polar coordinates.

Comment: @Jean Marie Yes, I can see as it's symmetric but how do we do that even in the first quadrant

Comment: Is differentiable calculus available to you?

Comment: Yes yes, I know the basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry, one need only consider the $x,y \geqslant 0$.
The points in the region considered that also lie on the coordinate axes are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, and their distance to the origin is $1$.
Notice that in general, the distance to the distance of $(x,y)$ to the origin is $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

We may hence reframe the definition of *good* as: $a>0$ is *good* when all $x,y>0$ with $x^a + y^a = 1$ are such that $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} > 1$.
Because $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} > 1\iff x^2 + y^2 > 1$, we may then rephrase the problem as

> $a>0$ is *good* when all $x,y>0$ with $x^a + y^a = 1$ are such that $x^2 + y^2 > 1$.
>   Which $a$ are good?

It follows immediately that $2$ is not good.
This will be useful later.
Now, write $y^2 = {\left(y^a\right)}^{2/a} = {\left(1-x^a\right)}^{2/a}$, so we can look for the minimum of

$$f(x) = x^2 + {\left(1-x^a\right)}^{2/a},$$

where $0\leqslant x\leqslant 1$.
The minimum is hence either when $x=0$, when $x=1$ or when $f'(x) = 0$.
On the one hand, we have $f(0) = f(1) = 1$.
On the other,

$$\begin{align}
f'(x) &= 2x + \frac2a {\left(1-x^a\right)}^{2/a - 1} (-ax^{a-1})
\\&= 2\left(x - {\left(1-x^a\right)}^{2/a - 1} x^{a-1}\right)
\end{align}$$

and hence

$$\begin{align}
f'(x) = 0 &\iff x = {\left(1-x^a\right)}^{2/a - 1} x^{a-1}
\\&\iff x^{2-a} = {\left(1-x^a\right)}^{(2-a)/a}
\\&\iff x^{a(2-a)} = {\left(1-x^a\right)}^{(2-a)}.
\end{align}$$

If $a \neq 2$, we can proceed as follows:

$$\begin{align}
f'(x) = 0 &\iff x^a = 1-x^a
\\&\iff 2x^a = 1
\iff x = {(1/2)}^{1/a}
\end{align}$$

Finally, with $x_a = {(1/2)}^{1/a}$,  we have $f\left(x_a\right) = 2^{1-2/a}$.
It follows that

$$f(x_a) > 1 \iff 2^{1-2/a} > 1 \iff 1-\frac2a > 0 \iff a > 2.$$

Hence, when $a>2$, $f(x_a) > 1$ and $x_a$ is a maximum of $f$, so that the minimum is $f(0) = f(1) = 1$.
In other words, when $a>2$, $a$ is good.

Conversely, when $a<2$ we have $f(x_a) < 1 = f(0) = f(1)$, so $x_a$ is a minimum of $f$.
In this case, it is clear that $a$ is not good.

It follows that $a$ is good if and only if $a>2$.

Comment: Amazing sir, I understood everything, the very root of this question, and your explanation is so intuitive, I'm very happy  thanks a lot for this

Comment: Glad to have helped. It would still be instructive to look at the sets $S(a)$ in some graphing program (you coul try Wolfram Alpha I guess). They are related to what we call $p$-norms.